# Symfony 2.8 custom constraint on 2 fields

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form which I create in my class ItemType:

```
class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class,
                array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('shortname', TextType::class,
                array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('somethingelse', TextType::class,
                array(
                    'constraints' => array(
                         new NotBlank()
                    )
                )
            )
        ;
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'item';
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Item',
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

now what I want to do is write a custom constraint that makes sure either name or shortname is filled. How can I achieve this? That is a constraint that should be on the form and not on a field... right? Or do I use validation_groups for that? If so - how do I add a constraint to a validation_group?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [callback constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) can be used to implement more involved validation rules:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Bundle\Entity\Item',
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
        'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            new Assert\Callback(['callback' => function (ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                $object = $context->getObject();

                if (null === $object->getName() && null === $object->getShortname()) {
                    $context->buildViolation('Either name or short name must be specified')->addViolation();
                }
            }]),
        ],
    ));
}
```

Comment: so is that common practice to do it like that? isn't writing my own constraints better? especially if I have more forms with 2 elements that are depedent on each other in the same way

Comment: I usually define validation rules using annotations but yes, this is common practice if you need it in one or two forms. If you need to use it in multiple form types then creating a custom constraint and a validator would be more DRY.

Comment: so how do I assign a custom constraint to a form?

Comment: The same way I assigned the *Callback* constraint. It would have to be a class constraint, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator